# Storing and printing 10+ digit integer in c++

Tags: c++

I'm using cout to print digits to the console. I am also storing values of up to 13+billion as a digit and doing computations on it. What data type should I use?

When I do the following:

```
int a = 6800000000;
cout << a;
```

It prints -1789934592.

thanks.

Comment: Use: `std::cout << sizeof(int) << "\n";` to see how many bytes the integer is using. A bit of maths from there will tell you the largest storable number. Other types are `long` and `long long`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`long long` can hold up to 9223372036854775807. Use something like [`gmp`](http://gmplib.org/) if you need larger.

Comment: +1 - `long long` is 8 bytes in GCC and VC++ regardless of the platform

Comment: @PotatoSwatter: Wrong - in both standards that define it (C99 and C++0x) it's 64 bits _minimum_. There would be no point in adding a 32 bits minimum type; we already have `long`. Furthermore, `int64_t` is pretty much by definition NOT FASTER than `long long`, as the latter type has less requirements (in particular, long long may be more than 64 bits)

Comment: Sure: if the native integer format is 128 bits, a "precisely 64 bits" type requires an `&= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` operation to be inserted at many points. The more common example where lower precision is slower to boot is 64/80 bits FP operations on x87.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm looking at §3.9.1 in N3000 and see nothing about specific requirements on the size of anything. Instead, it requires a typedef `int_least64_t` (§18.4.1). This seems totally incompatible with your assertion. Furthermore, fetching a 64-bit number will always be faster (amortized time) than fetching 128 bits, no matter what the ALU does.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's Annex E in the C99 standard: "The
minimum magnitudes shown shall be replaced by implementation-defined magnitudes with the same sign."  And it is there required that `LLONG_MAX >= +9223372036854775807` and `LLONG_MIN <= -9223372036854775807`, hence a minimum of 64-bits for `long long`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [int64_t](http://linux.die.net/man/3/int64_t) to guarantee you won't overflow.  It is available from [stdint.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html).

Comment: `int64_t` won't guarantee that generally! You can exceed its capacity, too.

Comment: "you" as in the OP who's storing up to ~13 billion.  Obviously, `int64_t` can still overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that both `int64_t` and `long long` are included in C99 and in C++ 0x, but *not* in the current version of C++. As such, using either does put your code at some risk of being non-portable. Realistically, however, that risk is probably already pretty low -- to the point that when/if you port your code, there are likely to be much bigger problems.

If, however, you really want to assure against that possibility, you might consider using a double precision floating point. Contrary to popular belief, floating point types can represent integers exactly up to a certain limit -- that limit being set (in essence) by the size of the mantissa in the F.P. type. The typical implementation of a double has a 53-bit mantissa, so you can represent 53-bit integers with absolute precision. That supports numbers up to 9,007,199,254,740,992 (which is substantially more than 13 of *either* of the popular meanings of "billion").

Comment: what is the datatype I would use for that 53-bit? double?

Comment: @Shawn:yes. Of course, you do have to be careful -- for example, if you divide two of them, you'll get floating point division, not integer division...

Comment: @Shawn: you will run into more portability problems by requiring an FPU than by requiring the ability to do 64-bit math.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:I can't imagine how you'd figure that. Most 32-bit CPUs include an FPU. Just for example, the last Intel x86 without an FPU was the 486sx, introduced around 1991 or so. By contrast, the first Intel x86s to support 64-bit integer math in hardware were some of the very last Pentium IV's, introduced around 2006 or so. Regardless of using an FPU per se, every C++ and C standard back to C89 has required a double with at least 10 digits of precision.

Comment: Some CPU's don't have FPUs, for example embedded (which covers A LOT) and DSP. On the other hand, most CPUs of any kind support extended-precision arithmetic. You can often use `uint64_t` on a 16-bit processor. It just requires 4 chained extended-precision addition instructions — far faster than software FP.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:While it's certainly true that hardware varies, we're left with one simple fact: every conforming implementation of C++ *must* include double, and double *must* support at least 10 digits of precision. By contrast, *no* C++ compiler is required to support a 64-bit integer type. Even in C++ 0x, int64_t will be *optional*, not required. If you write code for a Microchip PIC (for example) it may lack an FPU -- but it probably won't support int64_t either. *Some* sort of support for a conforming double is much more widespread than support of int64_t.

Comment: Point taken, but in practice software support for `int64_t` and for `double` go hand-in-hand. I checked the PIC C compiler manual (for the smaller chips) http://www.microchip.com/Microchip.WWW.SecureSoftwareList/secsoftwaredownload.aspx?device=en542849&lang=en&ReturnURL=http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en542849# , and it provides neither. It's simply non-compliant, like many others.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Not even close to true. Just for a few obvious examples, all the 486DX, Pentium, Pentium Pro, Pentium II, Pentium III and most Pentium IV machines had FPUs, but no direct 64-bit support. Likewise, virtually all PowerPC based Macs. Likewise about a bajillion ARM processors, such as in your average mobile phone. Likewise a zillion SPARCs, SuperSPARCs, MicroSPARCs. Likewise, anything with a 68020, 68030, 68040, etc. I won't bore you with more, but you get the idea...

Comment: @Jerry: 64-bit support does not require 64-bit hardware. I've used `int64_t` on the 68000, long ago. We can pretty much ignore both 64-bit registers and FPUs for the purposes of this argument.

Comment: Also, see what the standard actually says about `double`: "The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined." (§3.9.1/8) There must be some type called `double`, but it is only what you expect if `numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559 == true`.

Comment: The `double` implementation doesn't matter. `double` must have at least 12 significant digits, independent of the precise representation. 13 billion takes only 11 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Your data type (int) is too small to hold such large numbers. You should use a larger data type or one of the fixed size data types as given in the other answer (though you should really use uint64_t if you're not using negative numbers).

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to understand the range limits of different sized types.

A 32 bit type (on most 32 bit platforms, both int and long are 32 bit) have the following ranges:

```
signed: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned: 0 to 4,294,967,295
```

While 64 bit types (typically long long's are 64 bit, on most Unix 64 bit platforms a long is also 64) have the following range:

```
signed: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
unsigned: 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

Comment: I thought VC++'s long long was 64 bits also in 32 bit Windows?

Comment: @Maneul - it is, let me clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

just use double in the declaration statement

Answer (score -1):

You could use a long int:

```
long int a
```

Or if it's always going to be positive, an unsigned long int:

```
unsigned long int a
```

See: http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=131678

Answer (score -1):

unsigned long long

can be used

Comment: You need to add some more details, an example, and maybe a link to some documentation